# JavaScript: alter keyboard behaviour

Tags: javascript, unicode, keyboard-events, behavior

I found this powerful script by James Naughton to alter the keyboard behaviour in order to have a text conversion on the fly to Unicode Greek using a standard western keyboard ([Unicode Classical Greek Inputter](http://users.ox.ac.uk/~tayl0010/polytonic-greek-inputter.html)).

That would be very useful to me, but unfortunately I'm a newbie on Javascript and I can't make it work as I wish.

I guess (but I'm not sure) that this is the only part of the code responsible for the conversion:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function keyd(e) {
storeCaret(this);
if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Mozilla') > -1) {
e = (e)?e:window.event;
keyCode=(e.keyCode)?e.keyCode:e.which;}
doit();
}

if (document.all | navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Mozilla') > -1 | navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Netscape') > -1) {
document.onkeyup = keyd;}

function setSelectionRange(input, selectionStart, selectionEnd) {
  if (input.setSelectionRange) {
    input.focus();
    input.setSelectionRange(selectionStart, selectionEnd);
  }
}

function setCaretToPos (input, pos) {
  setSelectionRange(input, pos, pos);
}



function replace(inText,inFindStr,inReplStr) {

   var searchFrom = 0;
   var offset = 0;
   var outText = '';
   var searchText = '';

      searchText = inText;

   offset = searchText.indexOf(inFindStr,searchFrom);
   while (offset != -1 ) {
      outText += inText.substring(searchFrom,offset);
      outText += inReplStr;
      searchFrom = offset + inFindStr.length;
      offset = searchText.indexOf(inFindStr,searchFrom);
   }
   outText += inText.substring(searchFrom,inText.length);

   return (outText);
if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('MSIE') > -1) {
setCaretAtEnd(document.pgk.pgk);
storeCaret(document.pgk.pgk);
}
};



//thanks to Pablo Rodriguez for the keyboard routine
function doit() {


    text2 = document.pgk.pgk.value;


if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('MSIE') > -1) {

   var currentRange=document.selection.createRange();
  var workRange=currentRange.duplicate();

  // select the whole contents and get 'all' selection

   event.srcElement.select();
   var allRange=document.selection.createRange();

   var len=0;

  // NB text.length does not give the caret position

   while(workRange.compareEndPoints("StartToStart",allRange)>0)
  {
    workRange.moveStart("character",-1);
    len++;


  // recover the original selection

   currentRange.select()

  // len contains the caret position if no selection
  // or selection start point offset if any
  }
}

if (!document.all && navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Mozilla') > -1) {
var input2 = document.getElementById('area');


if (input2.setSelectionRange) 
var len = input2.selectionStart;


if ( keyCode == 57 || keyCode == 48 || keyCode == 191 || keyCode == 220 || keyCode == 61 || keyCode == 109) len += -1;


}

var key = document.all ? event.keyCode : 0;

if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('MSIE') > -1) {
if ((event.shiftKey == false) && (key == 191))
len += -1;
if ((event.shiftKey == true) && (key == 57 || key == 48))
len += -1;
if ( key == 220 || key == 187 || key == 189 ) len += -1;
}


  if (key == 8 || key == 16 || key == 17 || key == 18 || key == 20 || key == 33 || key == 34 || key == 36 || key == 37 || key == 38 || key == 39 || key == 40 || key == 45 || key == 46) {
return ;
}


    text2 = replace(text2,'``','“');
    text2 = replace(text2,'\'\'','”');
    text2 = replace(text2,'´´','”');
    text2 = replace(text2,',,','„');
    text2 = replace(text2,'<<','«');
    text2 = replace(text2,'>>','»');
    text2 = replace(text2,':','·');
    text2 = replace(text2,'?',';');
    text2 = replace(text2,' )','᾽');

    text2 = replace(text2,'a','α');
    text2 = replace(text2,'α/','ά');
    text2 = replace(text2,'α\\','ὰ');
    text2 = replace(text2,'α=','ᾶ');
    text2 = replace(text2,'α)','ἀ');
    text2 = replace(text2,'α(','ἁ');
    text2 = replace(text2,'α_','ᾱ');
    text2 = replace(text2,'α-','ᾰ');
    text2 = replace(text2,'α|','ᾳ');
    text2 = replace(text2,'ἀ\\','ἂ');
    text2 = replace(text2,'ἀ/','ἄ');
    text2 = replace(text2,'ἁ\\','ἃ');
    text2 = replace(text2,'ἁ/','ἅ');
    text2 = replace(text2,'ἁ=','ἇ');
    text2 = replace(text2,'ἀ=','ἆ');
    text2 = replace(text2,'ά|','ᾴ');
    text2 = replace(text2,'ὰ|','ᾲ');
    text2 = replace(text2,'ἀ|','ᾀ');
    text2 = replace(text2,'ἁ|','ᾁ');
    text2 = replace(text2,'ᾶ|','ᾷ');
    text2 = replace(text2,'ἆ|','ᾆ');
    text2 = replace(text2,'ἇ|','ᾇ');
    text2 = replace(text2,'ἂ|','ᾂ');
    text2 = replace(text2,'ἄ|','ᾄ');
    text2 = replace(text2,'ἃ|','ᾃ');
    text2 = replace(text2,'ἅ|','ᾅ');

    text2 = replace(text2,'b','β');
    text2 = replace(text2,'c','ξ');
    text2 = replace(text2,'d','δ');

    text2 = replace(text2,'e','ε');
    text2 = replace(text2,'ε/','έ');
    text2 = replace(text2,'ε\\','ὲ');
    text2 = replace(text2,'ε)','ἐ');
    text2 = replace(text2,'ε(','ἑ');
    text2 = replace(text2,'ἐ\\','ἒ');
    text2 = replace(text2,'ἐ/','ἔ');
    text2 = replace(text2,'ἑ\\','ἓ');
    text2 = replace(text2,'ἑ/','ἕ');

    text2 = replace(text2,'f','φ');
    text2 = replace(text2,'g','γ');

    text2 = replace(text2,'h','η');
    text2 = replace(text2,'η/','ή');
    text2 = replace(text2,'η\\','ὴ');
    text2 = replace(text2,'η=','ῆ');
    text2 = replace(text2,'η)','ἠ');
    text2 = replace(text2,'η(','ἡ');
    text2 = replace(text2,'η|','ῃ');
    text2 = replace(text2,'ἠ\\','ἢ');
    text2 = replace(text2,'ἡ\\','ἣ');
    text2 = replace(text2,'ἠ/','ἤ');
    text2 = replace(text2,'ἡ/','ἥ');
    text2 = replace(text2,'ἠ=','ἦ');
    text2 = replace(text2,'ἡ=','ἧ');
    text2 = replace(text2,'ή|','ῄ');
    text2 = replace(text2,'ὴ|','ῂ');
    text2 = replace(text2,'ῆ|','ῇ');
    text2 = replace(text2,'ἠ|','ᾐ');
    text2 = replace(text2,'ἡ|','ᾑ');
    text2 = replace(text2,'ἢ|','ᾒ');
    text2 = replace(text2,'ἣ|','ᾓ');
    text2 = replace(text2,'ἤ|','ᾔ');
    text2 = replace(text2,'ἥ|','ᾕ');
    text2 = replace(text2,'ἦ|','ᾖ');
    text2 = replace(text2,'ἧ|','ᾗ');

    text2 = replace(text2,'i','ι');
    text2 = replace(text2,'ι/','ί');
    text2 = replace(text2,'ι\\','ὶ');
    text2 = replace(text2,'ι=','ῖ');
    text2 = replace(text2,'ι)','ἰ');
    text2 = replace(text2,'ι(','ἱ');
    text2 = replace(text2,'ἰ\\','ἲ');
    text2 = replace(text2,'ἱ/','ἵ');
    text2 = replace(text2,'ἰ/','ἴ');
    text2 = replace(text2,'ἱ\\','ἳ');
    text2 = replace(text2,'ἰ=','ἶ');
    text2 = replace(text2,'ἱ=','ἷ');
    text2 = replace(text2,'ι-','ῐ');
    text2 = replace(text2,'ι_','ῑ');
    text2 = replace(text2,'ι+','ϊ');
    text2 = replace(text2,'ϊ/','ΐ');
    text2 = replace(text2,'ϊ\\','ῒ');
    text2 = replace(text2,'ϊ=','ῗ');

    text2 = replace(text2,'j','ς');
    text2 = replace(text2,'k','κ');
    text2 = replace(text2,'l','λ');
    text2 = replace(text2,'m','μ');
    text2 = replace(text2,'n','ν');

    text2 = replace(text2,'o','ο');
    text2 = replace(text2,'ο/','ό');
    text2 = replace(text2,'ο\\','ὸ');
    text2 = replace(text2,'ο)','ὀ');
    text2 = replace(text2,'ο(','ὁ');
    text2 = replace(text2,'ὀ\\','ὂ');
    text2 = replace(text2,'ὁ\\','ὃ');
    text2 = replace(text2,'ὀ/','ὄ');
    text2 = replace(text2,'ὁ/','ὅ');

    text2 = replace(text2,'p','π');
    text2 = replace(text2,'q','θ');

    text2 = replace(text2,'r','ρ');
    text2 = replace(text2,'ρ)','ῤ');
    text2 = replace(text2,'ρ(','ῥ');

    text2 = replace(text2,'s','σ');
    text2 = replace(text2,'t','τ');

    text2 = replace(text2,'u','υ');
    text2 = replace(text2,'υ/','ύ');
    text2 = replace(text2,'υ\\','ὺ');
    text2 = replace(text2,'υ=','ῦ');
    text2 = replace(text2,'υ)','ὐ');
    text2 = replace(text2,'υ(','ὑ');
    text2 = replace(text2,'ὐ\\','ὒ');
    text2 = replace(text2,'ὑ\\','ὓ');
    text2 = replace(text2,'ὐ/','ὔ');
    text2 = replace(text2,'ὑ/','ὕ');
    text2 = replace(text2,'ὐ=','ὖ');
    text2 = replace(text2,'ὑ=','ὗ');
    text2 = replace(text2,'υ+','ϋ');
    text2 = replace(text2,'ϋ/','ΰ');
    text2 = replace(text2,'ϋ\\','ῢ');
    text2 = replace(text2,'ϋ=','ῧ');
    text2 = replace(text2,'υ_','ῡ');
    text2 = replace(text2,'υ-','ῠ');

    text2 = replace(text2,'v','ϝ');

    text2 = replace(text2,'w','ω');
    text2 = replace(text2,'ω/','ώ');
    text2 = replace(text2,'ω\\','ὼ');
    text2 = replace(text2,'ω=','ῶ');
    text2 = replace(text2,'ω)','ὠ');
    text2 = replace(text2,'ω(','ὡ');
    text2 = replace(text2,'ω|','ῳ');
    text2 = replace(text2,'ὠ/','ὤ');
    text2 = replace(text2,'ὡ/','ὥ');
    text2 = replace(text2,'ὠ\\','ὢ');
    text2 = replace(text2,'ὡ\\','ὣ');
    text2 = replace(text2,'ὠ=','ὦ');
    text2 = replace(text2,'ὡ=','ὧ');
    text2 = replace(text2,'ώ|','ῴ');
    text2 = replace(text2,'ὼ|','ῲ');
    text2 = replace(text2,'ῶ|','ῷ');
    text2 = replace(text2,'ὠ|','ᾠ');
    text2 = replace(text2,'ὡ|','ᾡ');
    text2 = replace(text2,'ὤ|','ᾤ');
    text2 = replace(text2,'ὥ|','ᾥ');
    text2 = replace(text2,'ὢ|','ᾢ');
    text2 = replace(text2,'ὣ|','ᾣ');
    text2 = replace(text2,'ὦ|','ᾦ');
    text2 = replace(text2,'ὧ|','ᾧ');

    text2 = replace(text2,'x','χ');
    text2 = replace(text2,'y','ψ');
    text2 = replace(text2,'z','ζ');

    text2 = replace(text2,'A','Α');
    text2 = replace(text2,'Α/','Ά');
    text2 = replace(text2,'Α\\','Ὰ');
    text2 = replace(text2,'Α(','Ἁ');
    text2 = replace(text2,'Α)','Ἀ');
    text2 = replace(text2,'Α|','ᾼ');
    text2 = replace(text2,'Ἁ\\','Ἃ');
    text2 = replace(text2,'Ἀ\\','Ἂ');
    text2 = replace(text2,'Ἁ/','Ἅ');
    text2 = replace(text2,'Ἀ/','Ἄ');
    text2 = replace(text2,'Ἁ=','Ἇ');
    text2 = replace(text2,'Ἀ=','Ἆ');
    text2 = replace(text2,'Ἁ|','ᾉ');
    text2 = replace(text2,'Ἀ|','ᾈ');
    text2 = replace(text2,'Ἃ|','ᾋ');
    text2 = replace(text2,'Ἂ|','ᾊ');
    text2 = replace(text2,'Ἅ|','ᾍ');
    text2 = replace(text2,'Ἄ|','ᾌ');
    text2 = replace(text2,'Ἇ|','ᾏ');
    text2 = replace(text2,'Ἆ|','ᾎ');
    text2 = replace(text2,'Α-','Ᾰ');
    text2 = replace(text2,'Α_','Ᾱ');

    text2 = replace(text2,'B','Β');
    text2 = replace(text2,'C','Ξ');
    text2 = replace(text2,'D','Δ');

    text2 = replace(text2,'E','Ε');
    text2 = replace(text2,'Ε/','Έ');
    text2 = replace(text2,'Ε\\','Ὲ');
    text2 = replace(text2,'Ε)','Ἐ');
    text2 = replace(text2,'Ε(','Ἑ');
    text2 = replace(text2,'Ἐ\\','Ἒ');
    text2 = replace(text2,'Ἐ/','Ἔ');
    text2 = replace(text2,'Ἑ\\','Ἓ');
    text2 = replace(text2,'Ἑ/','Ἕ');

    text2 = replace(text2,'F','Φ');
    text2 = replace(text2,'G','Γ');

    text2 = replace(text2,'H','Η');
    text2 = replace(text2,'Η\\','Ὴ');
    text2 = replace(text2,'Η/','Ή');
    text2 = replace(text2,'Η)','Ἠ');
    text2 = replace(text2,'Η(','Ἡ');
    text2 = replace(text2,'Η|','ῌ');
    text2 = replace(text2,'Ἠ\\','Ἢ');
    text2 = replace(text2,'Ἠ/','Ἤ');
    text2 = replace(text2,'Ἠ=','Ἦ');
    text2 = replace(text2,'Ἡ\\','Ἣ');
    text2 = replace(text2,'Ἡ/','Ἥ');
    text2 = replace(text2,'Ἡ=','Ἧ');
    text2 = replace(text2,'Ἠ|','ᾘ');
    text2 = replace(text2,'Ἡ|','ᾙ');
    text2 = replace(text2,'Ἢ|','ᾚ');
    text2 = replace(text2,'Ἤ|','ᾜ');
    text2 = replace(text2,'Ἦ|','ᾞ');
    text2 = replace(text2,'Ἣ|','ᾛ');
    text2 = replace(text2,'Ἥ|','ᾝ');
    text2 = replace(text2,'Ἧ|','ᾟ');

    text2 = replace(text2,'I','Ι');
    text2 = replace(text2,'Ι\\','Ὶ');
    text2 = replace(text2,'Ι/','Ί');
    text2 = replace(text2,'Ι)','Ἰ');
    text2 = replace(text2,'Ι(','Ἱ');
    text2 = replace(text2,'Ἰ\\','Ἲ');
    text2 = replace(text2,'Ἰ/','Ἴ');
    text2 = replace(text2,'Ἱ\\','Ἳ');
    text2 = replace(text2,'Ἱ\\','Ἵ');
    text2 = replace(text2,'Ἰ=','Ἶ');
    text2 = replace(text2,'Ἱ=','Ἷ');
    text2 = replace(text2,'Ι-','Ῐ');
    text2 = replace(text2,'Ι_','Ῑ');
    text2 = replace(text2,'Ι+','Ϊ');

    text2 = replace(text2,'J','*');
    text2 = replace(text2,'K','Κ');
    text2 = replace(text2,'L','Λ');
    text2 = replace(text2,'M','Μ');
    text2 = replace(text2,'N','Ν');

    text2 = replace(text2,'O','Ο');
    text2 = replace(text2,'Ο\\','Ὸ');
    text2 = replace(text2,'Ο/','Ό');
    text2 = replace(text2,'Ο(','Ὁ');
    text2 = replace(text2,'Ο)','Ὀ');
    text2 = replace(text2,'Ὁ\\','Ὃ');
    text2 = replace(text2,'Ὁ/','Ὅ');
    text2 = replace(text2,'Ὀ\\','Ὂ');
    text2 = replace(text2,'Ὀ/','Ὄ');

    text2 = replace(text2,'P','Π');
    text2 = replace(text2,'Q','Θ');

    text2 = replace(text2,'R','Ρ');
    text2 = replace(text2,'Ρ(','Ῥ');

    text2 = replace(text2,'S','Σ');
    text2 = replace(text2,'T','Τ');

    text2 = replace(text2,'U','Υ');
    text2 = replace(text2,'Υ/','Ύ');
    text2 = replace(text2,'Υ\\','Ὺ');
    text2 = replace(text2,'Υ(','Ὑ');
    text2 = replace(text2,'Ὑ\\','Ὓ');
    text2 = replace(text2,'Ὑ/','Ὕ');
    text2 = replace(text2,'Ὑ=','Ὗ');
    text2 = replace(text2,'Υ-','Ῠ');
    text2 = replace(text2,'Υ_','Ῡ');
    text2 = replace(text2,'Υ+','ϔ');

    text2 = replace(text2,'V','Ϝ');

    text2 = replace(text2,'W','Ω');
    text2 = replace(text2,'Ω\\','Ὼ');
    text2 = replace(text2,'Ω/','Ώ');
    text2 = replace(text2,'Ω)','Ὠ');
    text2 = replace(text2,'Ω(','Ὡ');
    text2 = replace(text2,'Ω|','ῼ');
    text2 = replace(text2,'Ὠ\\','Ὢ');
    text2 = replace(text2,'Ὠ/','Ὤ');
    text2 = replace(text2,'Ὠ=','Ὦ');
    text2 = replace(text2,'Ὡ\\','Ὣ');
    text2 = replace(text2,'Ὡ/','Ὥ');
    text2 = replace(text2,'Ὡ=','Ὧ');
    text2 = replace(text2,'Ὠ|','ᾨ');
    text2 = replace(text2,'Ὡ|','ᾩ');
    text2 = replace(text2,'Ὢ|','ᾪ');
    text2 = replace(text2,'Ὤ|','ᾬ');
    text2 = replace(text2,'Ὦ|','ᾮ');
    text2 = replace(text2,'Ὣ|','ᾫ');
    text2 = replace(text2,'Ὥ|','ᾭ');
    text2 = replace(text2,'Ὧ|','ᾯ');

    text2 = replace(text2,'X','Χ');
    text2 = replace(text2,'Y','Ψ');
    text2 = replace(text2,'Z','Ζ');

document.pgk.pgk.value = text2;

if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('MSIE') > -1) {
document.pgk.pgk.focus();

    var range = document.pgk.pgk.createTextRange();
    range.moveStart("character",len);
    range.collapse(), range.select();
}

if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Mozilla') > -1) {


var obj=document.pgk.pgk;

obj.focus();

obj.scrollTop=obj.scrollHeight;

      setCaretToPos(document.pgk.pgk, len);
}
else document.pgk.pgk.value = text2;
storeCaret(document.pgk.pgk);
}


function GkPoly (replaceString) {
var input = document.getElementById('area');

if (input.setSelectionRange) {
var selectionStart = input.selectionStart;
var selectionEnd = input.selectionEnd;

input.value = input.value.substring(0, selectionStart)
                  + replaceString
                  + input.value.substring(selectionEnd);

var obj=document.pgk.pgk;

obj.focus();

obj.scrollTop=obj.scrollHeight;


    if (selectionStart != selectionEnd) // has there been a selection 
      {setSelectionRange(input, selectionStart, selectionStart + replaceString.length);}

    else // set caret 
      {setCaretToPos(input, selectionStart + replaceString.length);}
return;
}


if (document.selection && navigator.userAgent.indexOf('MSIE') > -1) {
insertAtCaret(input, replaceString);
 document.pgk.pgk.focus();
}
else {
input.value += replaceString;
  }
}


</script>
```

What I'm trying to do is:

1. identify the right portion of code and load it as a separate .js file;
2. apply the script to the following:

```
<div class="input-group">
<span class="input-group-addon"><strong>Greek text</strong></span>
<input id="grk1" class="form-control" placeholder="Type Greek letters here...">
<span class="input-group-addon">
<input type="checkbox">&nbsp;&nbsp;With diacritics
</span>
</div>

[...]

<div class="input-group">
<span class="input-group-addon"><strong>Greek text</strong></span>
<input id="grk2" class="form-control" placeholder="Type Greek letters here...">
<span class="input-group-addon">
<input type="checkbox">&nbsp;&nbsp;With diacritics
</span>
</div>
```

so that the targets of the script are **#grk1** and **#grk2** at the same time.

I made a great deal of attempts, but I have been constantly failing: that's frustrating!

Thanks for reading and for your patience.